# Question about res.render and calling methods in the EJS file

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I created a practice function on another file, which I imported into my server.js file as I am just playing around with node and testing what works and what doesn't.

I am using express as a framework and when I pass the function in the res.render object and give the function a parameter in the res.render scope, it works no problem.

```
app.get('/projects', (req, res) => {
res.render('projects', {
    pageTitle: "Projects Page",
    allCaps: practice.screamIt("this will be all caps")
});
});
```

"This will be all caps" is outputed to the screen when I call it in my projects.ejs file like so `<h1><%-allCaps%></h1>`

What I am trying to do is to pass the parameter in the ejs file by calling `<%allCaps('capitalize this string')%>` But it doesn't seem to work.

When I create a function directly in the server.js file using app.locals like so...

`app.locals.addSum = (a,b) => {
    return a + b
};`

I have no issues passing parameters to said function from my ejs file...

```
<h1><%-addSum(10, 15)%></h1>
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve calling my other function from the EJS file? Or is it only possible using app.locals.

EDIT found how to do it:

Hi Guys i just passed the require statement through the object like so

```
const practice = require('./public/functions/practice.js')    
app.get('/projects', (req, res) => {
    res.render('projects', {
        pageTitle: "Projects Page",
        practice: practice
    });
});
```

And called it in the ejs file like so

```
<h1><%-practice.screamIt('capitilize this')%></h1>
```

Issue is solved!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT found how to do it:

Hi Guys i just passed the require statement through the object like so

```
const practice = require('./public/functions/practice.js')    
app.get('/projects', (req, res) => {
    res.render('projects', {
        pageTitle: "Projects Page",
        practice: practice
    });
});
```

And called it in the ejs file like so

```
<h1><%-practice.screamIt('capitilize this')%></h1>
```

Issue is solved!